# How to send HTML email through Outlook with a different mail-from (win32com.client)

Tags: python, winapi, outlook, email-client, win32com

**Brief background:**

I'm writing a script to send a template for work, but I normally send messages as our team mailer for visibility within my team. Most of it is working as expected, but I am missing the mail-from action or I'm doing something wrong. Normally I just select the alternate sender in Outlook when I craft the message from the "FROM" drop-down menu.

[image]

**Which attribute will let me specify a different sending address?**

Something like:

```
newMail.From = "mailer@my.org"
```

Simplified version of what I'm working with to send an HTML body:

```
import win32com.client
olMailItem = 0x0
obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = "the subject"
#newMail.Body = "body text"
newMail.HTMLBody  = """<a href="https://google.com">Google Link</a>"""
newMail.To = "customer@example.org"
#newMail.CC = 'Bob'
#attachment1 = "c:\\mypic.jpg"
#newMail.Attachments.Add(attachment1)
newMail.Send()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it:

```
newMail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "mailer@company.com"
```

That allowed me to send the message as our mailing list using my user profile.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`MailItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem_members(v=office.15).aspx) docs in the Outlook Object Model, what you want is the [`Sender`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.sender(v=office.15).aspx) property:

> Returns or sets an AddressEntry object that corresponds to the user of the account from which the MailItem is sent. Read/write.

In the remarks:

> In a session where multiple accounts are defined in the profile, you can set this property to specify the account from which to send a mail item. Set this property to the `AddressEntry` object of the user that is represented by the `CurrentUser` property of a specific account.
>
> If you set the `Sender` property to an `AddressEntry` that does not have permissions to send messages on that account, Outlook will raise an error.

So, if "mailer@my.org" has permissions to send through your Outlook account, this is how you do it; if it doesn't, there is no way to do it.

The "See Also" section has a link to a complete example (in C#, but you should be able to translate).